# UIImagePickerController edit view does not crop a square image on an iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I use an `UIImagePickerController` to let the user choose an image. I need the image in a square size. That's why I use the "edit" view to crop it to a square form. After reading the documentation, the `editedImage`sizes should be 320 by 320 pixel.

On an iPhone, this works as expected. If I use it on an iPad (included in a popover view) the view is 320 by 370. This behavior is weird (for me).

What step I missed out to get a squared photo from the picker (which picks from the photo library)?

**My source**

The source is included in an `UIAlertAction` definition closure.

```
        self.imagePicker.sourceType             = .PhotoLibrary
        self.imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover

        let imageViewBounds                                                   = self.imageView.bounds
        self.imagePicker.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections    = .Right
        self.imagePicker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView                  = self.imageView
        self.imagePicker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect                  = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: imageViewBounds.minX, y: avatarImageViewBounds.midY),
                                                                                             size: CGSize())
        self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```